# broken korean characters in a server

Tags: php, wordpress

i have the following script, which is scraping a page to find addresses:

```
require VENDOR_DIR.'/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

class AddrFind{

    function __construct(){
        $this->init();
    }

    function init(){
        add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'add_js'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_search_address', array($this, 'search_address'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_address', array($this, 'search_address'));
    }

    function add_js(){
        wp_enqueue_script('addr-script', LIB_URL.'/js/addrfind.js');
        wp_localize_script('addr-script', 'AddrFind', array(
            'ajaxurl'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ));
    }

    function search_address(){
        $q = $_POST['addr'];
        $page = $_POST['page'];
        $protocol = 'http';
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off'){
            $protocol = 'https';
        }
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        try{
            $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://postcode.map.daum.net/search', array(
                'headers'=>array(
                    'User-Agent'=>'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36'
                ),
                'query' => array(
                    "region_name"=>$q,
                    "cq"=>$q,
                    "cpage"=>$page,
                    "origin"=>$protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
                    "isp"=>"N",
                    "isgr"=>"N",
                    "isgj"=>"N",
                    "ongr"=>"N",
                    "ongj"=>"N",
                    "regionid"=>"",
                    "regionname"=>"",
                    "roadcode"=>"",
                    "roadname"=>"",
                    "banner"=>"on",
                    "indaum"=>"off",
                    "vt"=>"popup",
                    "am"=>"on",
                    "ani"=>"off",
                    "mode"=>"transmit",
                    "sd"=>"on",
                    "hmb"=>"off",
                    "heb"=>"off",
                    "smh"=>"off",
                    "theme"=>"",
                    "sit"=>"",
                    "sgit"=>"",
                    "sbit"=>"",
                    "pit"=>"",
                    "mit"=>"",
                    "lcit"=>"",
                    "plrg"=>"",
                    "plrgt"=>"1.5",
                    "zn"=>"Y",
                    "CWinWidth"=>"1280",
                    "sptype"=>"",
                    "sporgq"=>"",
                    "fullpath"=>""
                )
            ));

            $html = $response->getBody();

            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadHTML($html);

            // echo $html;

            // die();

            $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
            // $addrs = $xpath->query('//dd[contains(@class, "main_address")]//a[@class="link_post"]/span[@class="txt_addr"]');
            $addrs = $xpath->query('//ul[contains(@class, "list_post")]/li');
            $total_pages = $xpath->query('//div[@class="inner_paging"]/span[@class="num_page"]/following-sibling::text()[1]');

            $output = new stdClass;
            $output->total_pages = ($total_pages->length > 0) ? preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $total_pages->item(0)->nodeValue):0;
            $output->result = array();

            foreach($addrs as $addr){
                $building = (strlen($addr->getAttribute('data-building_name')) > 0) ? '('.$addr->getAttribute('data-building_name').')':'';

                $address = new stdClass;
                $address->road = $addr->getAttribute('data-addr').' '.$building;
                $address->zip = $addr->getAttribute('data-zonecode');
                $output->result[] = $address;
                // $result[] = $addr->nodeValue;
                // 
                echo $addr->getAttribute('data-addr');
            }

            echo json_encode($output);
        }catch(RequestException $e){
            print_r($e);
        }

        wp_die();
    }
}
```

nothing wrong with the code in my localhost, line `echo $addr->getAttribute('data-addr');` display what it should be. but in live server that line become broken characters, unicode, here it is: `ìì¸ ê°ë¨êµ¬ ê°ë¨ëë¡146ê¸¸ 6ìì¸`

Comment: The problem is in the character encoding. You could try adding a header of `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge more likely `UTF-8` though ... `ISO-8859-1` isn't known for covering _that many_ Korean characters ;)

Comment: should i send that additional header in query or how? FYI: the response already in `Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`